# ANT build config with dependency on core files

Tags: apache, ant, dependencies, config

Currently working on a PHP/HTML/JS project that is made up of a 'core' directory and multiple individual 'product' directories.

Dir structure as follows...

```
Core
    JS
    PHP
Product1
    JS
    PHP
    build.xml
Product2
    JS
    PHP
    build.xml
```

The ANT build script lies in each respective product directory. When triggering an ANT build, the core files are copied into a deploy directory, then the respective product files are merged into (and overwritten if necessary) the same directory. ANT then runs Qunit, PHPUnit tests, concatenates and minimizes the javascript etc. This new deploy directory is then copied to the CI environment.

My question is, is this the best way of doing this? Is there a way to introduce versioning of the core files - so product1 might use v1.2 of core files?

This method also causes problems when running the application locally - effectively on every change of a file, the build script needs to be run again.

Does anyone have any suggestions of how to improve this?